# Laravel: Convert Eloquent collection to Array without converting elements

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

Is there a (simple) way to convert an Eloquent Collection to an actual array without converting the elements themselves?

I get in trouble when I try to pass the collection into a php method like `array_rand($collection)`. This gives me the error: `array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`.

I worked around this by using `$collection->shuffle()->first();` which works fine and of course I could loop over the collection and push all in an array, but just out of curiosity I wonder if I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 15):

My first thought was `$collection->toArray()` but that also converts the Eloquent models to arrays. But the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray) say that `$collection->all()` should avoid that.

> `toArray` also converts all of the collection's nested objects to an array. If you want to get the raw underlying array, use the `all` method instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-listing) collection helper:

> The all method returns the underlying array represented by the
>   collection:

```
collect([1, 2, 3])->all();

// [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to work for 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' indeed. Since I was getting the collection from an Eloquent model ('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection') I was under the impression that the all I used `SomeModel::all()` was already the same. But now I see that I need to do another all-call on the result: `SomeModel::all()->all()`.